# How can I merge two conflicting revisions of a document?

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I have two databases between which bidirectional replication is triggered.

In case the network link between them is broken, and changes are made on a particular document with the same Id in both databases, a conflict occurs and one of the revisions is likely to be chosen over the other after the link is recovered.

I would like to merge both conflicting revisions so as not to lose any changes. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a good chapter in the CouchDB book online here:
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html

You can also read from the wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts

Here is some excerpts.

Find the conflicts:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc._conflicts) {
    emit(doc._conflicts, null);
  }
}
```

Once you find the conflict you will have to determine how to merge the two documents. CouchDB makes no assumptions, so you have to do this yourself. This is because merging is a domain problem. Once you have a strategy for performing your merge you then deal with the docs.

Lets get the winner, and conflict documents

```
GET /db/bob?conflicts=true
```

> you will get the winner plus a _conflicts member containing an array of the revs of the other, conflicting revision(s). You can then fetch them individually using subsequent GET /db/bob?rev=xxxx operations.
>
> Once you have retrieved all the conflicting revisions, your application can then choose to display them all to the user. Or it could attempt to merge them, write back the merged version, and delete the conflicting versions - that is, to resolve the conflict permanently.
>
> As described above, you need to update one revision and delete all the conflicting revisions explicitly. This can be done using a single POST to _bulk_docs, setting "_deleted":true on those revisions you wish to delete.

I have pulled the above from the wiki and the CouchDB book, but I hope it makes it more clear on where to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan, it does throw some light.